Pod can't ping other worker node
Now, I successfully created a cluster including 1 master, 3 worker nodes. All cluster be communicated by Calico CNI
Master node: I have a IP static public be attach into node (special)
My error:
I created a pod ubuntu at node worker, then telnet to master node ( IP and 80 port) and was successful. All pods in the remaining worker nodes can do the same
But, when I deploy a pod at the master node, that pod cannot telnet any IP worker node.
I turned off all ufw in all nodes but can't solve this problem. Does anyone have any solution to help me, I've been stuck for 3 days now =((. Thanks enter image description here
Ip route for master node
enter image description here
Ip route for a worker node
enter image description here
